# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: extracting string from string

Tags: c#

I have a method that extracts a username from a string using conditionals to check common conventions, although it is resulting in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on the `GetPart` utility method, even after explicitly checking before calling it?

Here is the extraction method

```
public bool TryExtractUsernameFromString(string str, out string username)
{
    if (str.Contains("un: "))
    {
        username = GetPart(str, "un: ", " ");
    }
    else if (str.Contains("un:"))
    {
        username = str.Split(" ").Where(x => x.StartsWith("un:")).First().Substring(3);
    }
    else if (str.Contains("un- "))
    {
        username = str.IndexOf(" ", str.IndexOf("un- ") + 1) > 0 ? GetPart(str, "un- ", " ") : str[str.IndexOf("un- ")..str.Length];
    }
    else if (str.Contains("un-"))
    {
        username = str.Split(" ").Where(x => x.StartsWith("un-")).First().Substring(3);
    }
    else
    {
        username = "";
    }

    return username.Length > 0;
}
```

I am passing this as the first argument to `TryExtractUsernameFromString` (without quotes)

`"un- jennyfromtheblock"`

So it happens here,

```
else if (str.Contains("un- "))
{
    username = str.IndexOf(" ", (str.IndexOf("un- ") + 1)) > 0 ? GetPart(str, "un- ", " ") : str[str.IndexOf("un -")..str.Length];
}
```

But shouldn't be calling `GetPart()` if it doesn't contain a second space after the first one in the `str.Contains` check.

GetPart method:

```
public static string GetPart(string s, string start, string end)
{
    return s[(s.IndexOf(start) + start.Length)..s.IndexOf(end)];
}
```

Comment: `username = str.IndexOf(" ", str.IndexOf("un- ") + 1) > 0 ? GetPart(str, "un- ", " ") : str[str.IndexOf("un -")..str.Length];` just because you can write everything on one line does not mean that you should. In fact if you write this in a more sensible way I'm sure you'll find your problem easily

Comment: If you're referring to parentheses check my recent edit. It being one line has nothing to do with my debugging, I debug in a playground app where I extract the code into many lines.

Comment: Basically you have a *lot* of expressions in a single statement. I strongly suggest you split things out, so you can steps through each method call one at a time, and look at what the results are. Likewise I'd suggest that if you change `GetPart` so that the results of `s.IndexOf(start)` and `s.IndexOf(end)` are stored in local variables, it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: "I debug in a playground app where I extract the code into many lines" - so you should be able to present the code to *us* in that way as well, along with a [mcve]. The way the code is presented here makes it hard for us to help you. A complete example without the giant "several method calls per statement" lines would make it *much* easier to help you.

Comment: I personally would write it as a regular expression where you capture a particular group.

Comment: Also, Common how? If some app is sending junk data, perhaps they also have a validation recommendation.

Comment: Remove Any Spacing you don't need, don't program around it.  Get rid of Double spaces, spaces in front of special chars etc. Then work with the data. Unless spacing means something.

Comment: While all these comments will help the OP with how to program in a more robust way, should we not try to focus on the specific problem he is asking about?  This isn't the Software Engineering forum.

Comment: By common convention I am referring to archived data, and the most common ways the data is stored inside strings from this archived data. I apologise for not minimising the code into a more human readable form, I will attempt to update the code to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DanRayson looks correct; But I wanted to add there is likely a much cleaner approach to this.

If statements can suck, case statements aren't really better. If you assume any name could have 0 or more matches:

```
public static void CleanName(string nameString, List<string> badPrefixes)
{
    var matchedPrefixes = badPrefixes.Where(w => nameString.Contains(w) 
               && && nameString.IndexOf(w) == 0).ToList();
    foreach(var prefix in matchedPrefixes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameString.Replace(prefix, "").Trim());
    }   

    if (!matchedPrefixes.Any())
    {
       Console.WriteLine(nameString);
    }
}
```

Another option would be using `.FirstOrDefault` instead of selecting all of the matches. But essentially, just find the match(es) and then remove it, and finally trim spaces.

### Example

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> badPrefixes = new List<string>()
    {
       "un:",
        "un-",
        "un ",  
        "Un", //Fun example too     
    };
    
    string longUserName1 = "un- Austin";
    string riskyLongName = "un: theUndying";
    
    CleanName(longUserName1, badPrefixes);
    // output: Austin
    CleanName(riskyLongName, badPrefixes);
    // output: theUndying
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.IndexOf("un- ") + 1` is returning the index of the START + 1 of that substring.  Try using `str.IndexOf("un- ") + 4` instead.  That'll get you the index of the second space you're looking for.